# How can i create a form equal to another in runtime

Tags: vb.net

Can you help me??

I already tried:

```
Dim myform As Form = New Form
myform.Show()
```

Comment: you are creating a generic form using `As Form` (not an instance of a form in your project) you probably want something like `Dim myform As Form1 = New Form1`  or simply `Dim myform = New Form1()`

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
Dim myform = New Form1()
myform.Show()
```